# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error message in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access

I'm writing a project in Xcode, and can't seem to solve this error. I'm aware that I'm probably trying to access a released/un-initialised object somewhere, or am perhaps passing data to an objet that it doesn't understand, but I can't find the cause of the issue (i.e. the line where I am doing this). I've tried debugging using NSZombies, and that didn't work.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[1])
{
const int   TIME_QUANTUM = atoi(argv[2]);

int         totalTime = 0;      
int         blockedTime = 0;    
int         blockTime[100];     
int         exitTime[100];     
int         relTime[100];       
int         spawnTime[100];   
int         processID[100];    
char        state[100][32];     

int         microseconds = totalTime * 1000;
int         currentSector = ((int)((microseconds/1000000.0) * SECTORS_PER_SEC)) % DISK_SECTORS;

int runningTest;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 

char row[BUFSIZ];

while (fgets (row, sizeof(row), fp) != NULL) //ERROR IS RETURNED HERE
{
    int time;
    char eventType[32];
    int pid;
    int sector;

    sscanf(row, "%i %s %i %i ", &time, eventType, &pid, &sector);
```

There is some more code that follows, but it's excruciatingly long-winded and convoluted, and I don't think it has much relevance to the error. My initial hunch was that the problem has something to do with the "fp" call; that I might have botched the file opening and am trying to call on a non-existent object. I initially tried:

```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d" "%s" "%d" "%d", &time, state, &pid, &sector)!= EOF){
```

But, replaced it with what's currently there after some time. 
Does anyone know where the bad access is? I really have no clue. The file I'm supposed to be opening is a sample process schedule file, containing some info about the processes (when they spawn, exit and are blocked etc.). If someone could nudge me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Note: using `fscanf` not check `EOF` but check number of argument you passed.

Comment: Check if `fp` is NULL.

Comment: I believe it is null, but that's the problem; I don't know why it is. As far as I know, the way I've written my code to open the file is fine, so as long as I provide an argument (which I did), it shouldn't be null.

Comment: If you add `if (fp==NULL) perror("Can't open input file");` what does it print?